# Mysql query to laravel eloquent or query builder nested select

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I got the following code that gonna return the sum of `score` if `tgl` is `'2023-01-01'` and then that return value will be selected again to not show any null that the query find

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT `kodeSales`,
        `departemenId`,
        `tgl`, 
        (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tgl IN ('2023-01-01') THEN score END)) AS '1'
    FROM `history_penjualan` 
    WHERE `tgl` BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-30' 
        `departemenId` = '28' 
    GROUP BY `tgl`
) AS temp
WHERE '1' IS NOT NULL
```

How do I do this in laravel eloquent or query builder ?

Comment: I have add an answer check it. If you want to convert more queries try this website.
https://sql2builder.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

### Try this way,

I tried this and it works. but in here you can change the **->having()** statement as **havingRaw("'1' IS NOT NULL")** or I provided code also works.

```
$sum_of_score = DB::table('history_penjualan')
        ->select('kodeSales', 'departemenId', 'tgl', DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN tgl = '2023-01-01' THEN score END) AS '1'"))
        ->whereBetween('tgl', ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-30'])
        ->where('departemenId', '=', 28)
        ->groupBy('tgl')
        ->having('1', '!=', null)
        ->get();
```

- If you want to learn about Laravel queries refer the document.
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries

### or if you need query in dynamic try this way,

```
$query = DB::table('history_penjualan')
        ->select(DB::raw('kodeSales, departemenId, tgl, SUM(CASE WHEN tgl = "2023-01-01" THEN score END) as "1"'))
        ->whereBetween('tgl', ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-30'])
        ->where('departemenId', '=', '28')
        ->groupBy('tgl');

$final_data = $query->having('1', '<>', null)->get();
```

*If this is not your expected answer please leave a comment, I'll give another way to do this :)*

Comment: I kinda need what i ask because the query will be dynamic i will add a ton of `SUM` and `Having and/or Where` Clause

Comment: OK, I have edited my answer check it bro.